# List<interfaceI> vs List<? extends InterfaceI> in java

Tags: java, generics, collections, arraylist

Arraylist with `List<interfaceI>` and `List<? extends InterfaceI>` both will have objects of classes implementing interfaceI. Then when what should be used?

Comment: That depends on how you want to use your `List`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose `Foo` and `Bar` are two classes implementing `InterfaceI`.

The second one (`List<? extends InterfaceI>`) doesn't allow adding anything to the list (except null), since the type that the list contains is unknown: it could be a `List<Foo>` or a `List<Bar>`: you just don't know.

So you usually use this notation for a method **argument**, when you want the method to read the elements of the list passed as argument, and want the caller to be able to call your method with a `List<InterfaceI>`, a  `List<Foo>` or a `List<Bar>`. Using `List<InterfaceI>` as argument would only accept  lists of type `List<InterfaceI>`.

Let's take a concrete example: you want to compute the maximum double value of a list of numbers. Such a method doesn't need to add or set anything to the list. All it does is iterating on the elements, get each number and compute their maximum. The signature could be

```
 public double max(List<Number> list);
```

But then, you won't be able to do

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
max(ints);
```

The only way to call this method is to do

```
List<Number> ints = new ArrayList<>();
max(ints);
```

Whereas if you declare the method as

```
public double max(List<? extends Number> list);
```

then you can do

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
max(ints);
max(longs)
```

Comment: Can i add Integer objects to List<Number> ints = new ArrayList<>() and call max(ints). Then it will work.

Comment: Yes you can as Integer extends Number

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that if you declare your list as `List<? extends S> myList`, the `myList` variable can by list of any type that extends `S` so associations like shown below will work:

```
public class Clazz implements S{}
List<? extends S> myList = new List<Clazz>(); // its fine as Clazz extends S
List<? extends S> myList = new List<S>(); // its fine as well
List<? extends S> myList = new List<Object>(); // ooooops it wil not work
```

But in such case you will not be abe to `PUT` anything to such list as you cannot guarantee the exact type of object that is held by list implementation assigned to `myList`

If you declare `List<S> myList` than you will be able to `PUT` and `GET` objects from list, as you are sure what is in it, however assignments from above will not work!

```
public class Clazz implements S{}
List<S> myList = new List<Clazz>(); // no way! 
List<S> myList = new List<S>(); //thats perfectly fine! - You can PUT new S in it;
List<S> myList = new List<Object>(); //known result;
```

Answer (score 0):

here in place of this

```
public double max(List<? extends Number> list){
```

if you do like-

```
public List myList(List<? extends String> list){
list.add("string");// No, can not add anything in list except null
list.add(null);
}
```